# Create IIS Application from c#

Tags: c#, powershell, iis

I need to create an application on `IIS` server from my `.NET WinForm` application.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
New-Item "IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\Test" -type Application
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\Test" -Name applicationPool -Value "DefaultAppPool"
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\Test" -Name physicalPath -Value "D:\Temp\MyWebApp"
```

When I run this script in powershell console the application is created.

When I run this script in application by using PowerShell object in https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation.dll I get this error:

> Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Retrieving the
>   COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {688EEEE5-6A7E-422F-B2E1-6AF00DC944A6} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

this error will return three times.

My C# code is:

```
string script = @"Import-Module WebAdministration
New-Item ""IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\Test"" -type Application
Set-ItemProperty ""IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\Test"" -Name applicationPool -Value ""DefaultAppPool""
Set-ItemProperty ""IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\Test"" -Name physicalPath -Value ""D:\Temp\_PBWI\Destination""";


using (PowerShell powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    powerShellInstance.AddScript(script);

    Collection<PSObject> psOutput = powerShellInstance.Invoke();

    if (powerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var e in powerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Select(a => a.Exception).ToArray())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**SOLVED:** 
The problem was that the application was running 32-bit powershell instead of 64-bit

Comment: You need to publish your application which will create a setup.exe and subfolders like a commercial software package.  Use option to create CD but you can select any folder on your pc or network instead of a CD.  The windows dll on the server need to be updated which will get done when you run the setup.exe.

Comment: this application creating database and iis application by user iput. User fill the form and application should created iis application

Comment: VS uses windows dll and the dll on the server need updating to run your Net Library Application.  Not all the Net libraries are on the server.

Comment: on the same server, the same user run the same script in the console running without errors, through the application (PowerShell object of the System.Management.Automation.dll library) that throws an error. Why?

Comment: I s this a web application?  Usually with web applications you are actually running from the client.  Are the credential the same between console running without errors and with errors?

Comment: WinForm application... but problem is solved now